# Datatable search function not working, and styling tips

Tags: jquery, asp.net, vb.net, datatables

I am new to JQuery and asp.net, but have been asked to implement a datatable table using them both.

I have the following aspx page:

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" MasterPageFile="~/Masterpage.master" AutoEventWireup="false" MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="true"  CodeFile="View.aspx.vb" Inherits="MDGRenewals.page_views" %>
<%@ Register Src ="~/Webcontrols/Admin/Users/RoleManager.ascx" tagprefix="mdg" TagName="rolemanager" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="contentMain" runat="server">

        <asp:Repeater runat="server" id="DataGrid1" >

        <HeaderTemplate >
            <table id="pageviews" class="display">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        User ID
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Username
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        First Name
                    </th>
                </tr>    
                </thead>        
        </HeaderTemplate>

        <ItemTemplate >
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <%#Eval("user_id") %>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <%#Eval("page_name")%>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <%#Eval("Count") %>
                    </td>

                </tr>
                </tbody>
        </ItemTemplate>

        <FooterTemplate >
            </table>
        </FooterTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>


<html>

<head>

<!-- DataTables CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.4/css/jquery.dataTables.css">

<!-- jQuery -->
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>

<!-- jQuery -->
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>

<!-- jQuery -->
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.4/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<!-- DataTables -->
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.4/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#pageviews').DataTable();
            display: true
        });

    </script>

</head>

<body onload="">

</body>
</html>

</asp:Content>
```

I have a couple of problems:

1. The search box is not working the way it is on the datatables demo eg it does not eliminate entries from the table when typing into search the box.

2.I cannot work out how to style the table. I have tried the following:

```
display: true
```

but it does not work.

3. The first row on my table is coming out a different colour from the rest, almost like it is the result of a search.

The table is populating from a sql query in my aspx.vb page

Comment: Before getting into conclusion `"it does not work"`, make sure to check `"is it the correct way to do"`

Comment: @Bharadwaj The table is definitely having its display altered by datatables, and the documentation says searching should be implemented by default

Comment: @Bharadwaj http://www.datatables.net/manual/installation

Comment: @Bharadwaj "That's it! DataTables will add ordering, searching, paging and information to your table by default, giving your end users the ability to find the information they want as quickly as possible."

Comment: remove `display: true` it is wrong, may be it is preventing actual logic

Comment: And also remove `html`, `head` and `body` tags.

Comment: Put `alert(1);` before `$('#pageviews').DataTable();`, if you get `alert` its fine, otherwise add `http` or `https` to your `script` and `link` references

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed it.

The  tags were wrong, they should have been at the end of the table.

Effectively they were declaring a new table each time.